# Whats the difference between redirect and this in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, controller, this

I am new in Codeigniter and it's one of the good frameworks of php. But on some conditions I'm confused. Like this one. If any of you have any clarification about my dough, it's a great help for me.
Offcouse redirects refresh the page and $this not but apart from this I want to know - anyhow both of them used to go to somewhere else on view pages or like in other controller or in same controller to other methods.
But we don't use these side by side because when getting any of them it will go to that page or method without checking the next lines.

In case of a normal difference then have lot's of but I just want to know about the condition of going to next page or method when we use redirect or $this like this -

```
$this->Function($value); //It's method of same controller.
redirect('Controller/function'); //It's also doing same with page reload.
```

Thank for looking my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Redirect()**
When you will call any function of helper in codeigniter then you can call function directly without using any object. Helper in Codeigniter is collection of functions.

Redirect() method is a part of URL helper in Codeigniter.
For your ref. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

So, just load helper using $this->load->helper('url'); or you can also mention in autoload.php file.

**$this->Function();** used to call a function from same controller

Answer (score 1):

`$this->Function();` used to call a function from same controller

**redirect()**

While building a web application, we often need to redirect the user from one page to another page. CodeIgniter makes this job easy for us. The `redirect()` function is used for this purpose.

```
redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
```

The first argument can have two types of URI. We can pass full site URL or URI segments to the controller you want to direct.

The second optional parameter can have any of the three values from auto, location or refresh. The default is auto.

The third optional parameter is only available with location redirects and it allows you to send specific HTTP response code.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect means jumping to another function mentioned in the redirect method.

`$this->Function($value);` => jumping to another function and you can execute the code of the same function as well as pass the value back by returning value.

Answer (score 0):

When you send request to codeigniter generally CI controller gets called and then function which is mentioned in uri segment. like below... So this will be another request.

```
redirect('Controller/function'); //It's also doing same with page reload.
```

But when you have to call another function within the same request then you can use below approach

```
$this->Function($value); //It's method of same controller.
```

This will execute the given function and return the value within same request.

Comment: This is right but needs I need something like this and I stuck here with $this and redirect. It works but not that way which I want for my condition. I brief about it on the below reply. @danish and Skalbhile